# Error Testing My Data on api.parse.com Using Their Keys

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Parse.com and am trying to test the data I have created on their platform but it is not going through. I have followed the book am reading and it's time to test the data I have created on Parse but it's not working.
I am supposed to type the following address into the browser and receive all the data I have created under the "Products" class as JSON in the browser. I am doing it to test it if it is working.

```
https://<appID>:javascript-keys=<jsKEY>@api.parse.com/1/classes/Products
```

`appID` is replaced with my **Parse-applicationID** and `jsKEY` is replaced with my **Parse-JavascriptKEY**. When I enter the above address into the browser, a dialog box appears asking me to enter my username and password. I typed my www.Parse.com `username` and `password` but its not working.

First, I receive a confirmation box with the following message:

```
You are about to log in to the site "api.parse.com" with the username "<appID>".
```

appID is the application ID from parse.com

I will click OK and then I receive a prompt dialog box with two input fields for username and password. I enter my parse.com username and password but then it does not work. I also try to use the `<appID>` as the username and with the parse.com password but still it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog box means that the authentication failed, so they ask for your username and your password again. The URL scheme is `https://user:password@api.parse.com/1/classes/Products`. So when the dialog ask for your username and password it actually ask for your appID as username, and your jsKey (with the string "javascript-key=" in front of it) as password.

The issue here is that you are adding a `s` at the end of `key` in the string `javascript-key=`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now after removing the 's'